# Fit arima model with weekly data (quantmod)

Tags: r

I am working in R with weekly financial data downloaded directly from `quantmod`.

My question is, if I want to apply ARIMA models, is it necessary to transform the data to a time series (ts) or can I work directly with the closing prices (xts zoo) obtained from quantmod? I ask this question because I have directly used the auto.arima (`forecast` package) function with the closing prices obtained and it has proposed me a model, but I do not know if the procedure is quite correct.

If I finally need to transform such data to time series (ts), what is the process?

Is this correct?

```
getSymbols("^N225",from="1999-01-01", to = "2022-03-23", periodicity ="weekly")
N225C<-N225[,4]
```

I get data like this:

```
             N225.Close
1999-01-01   13536.56
1999-01-08   13738.86
1999-01-15   14245.42
1999-01-22   14342.32
1999-01-29   14086.85

structure(c(13536.55957, 13738.860352, 14245.419922, 14342.320313, 
14086.849609, 13952.400391, 14146.790039, 14470.450195, 14183.450195, 
15502.139648, 15717.919922, 15986.040039, 16327.55957, 16846.689453, 
16727.080078), class = c("xts", "zoo"), src = "yahoo", updated = structure(1648408487.85182, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), index = structure(c(915148800, 915753600, 916358400, 
916963200, 917568000, 918172800, 918777600, 919382400, 919987200, 
920592000, 921196800, 921801600, 922406400, 923011200, 923616000
), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(15L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, "N225.Close"))
```

Is this process correct?:

```
start = c(1999, 1)
tsnikkei<-ts(N225C, start = start, frequency = 52)
arimanikkei<-auto.arima(tsnikkei, trace = TRUE, lambda = 0)
```

Or can I directly use the closing prices?

```
 arimanikkei<-autoarima(N225C, trace = TRUE, lambda = 0)
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english

Comment: Both gives the same result.  `xts` is extensible time series object, where the data pulled is already 'weekly'

Comment: thanks, I had the doubt because both processes give me the same result but I need to apply more models (GARCH) and I didn't know if I could find differences later